# How to view mplus plots in r

Tags: r, hdf5

I'm working on a project using programs r and Mplus. On Macs, the Mplus program doesn't allow you to load plots directly but it interfaces with r to do so. Sadly, I've followed the directions provided by the Mplus website but can't seem to locate the "source code" file that they casually refer to. I've searched my computer and the internet for an r file called "mplus.R" to no avail. Does anyone have experience with this?

Here are the two sources from Mplus I've been following:

https://www.statmodel.com/mplus-R/

http://www.statmodel.com/mplus-R/Mplus%20R%20tutorial.pdf

I've loaded the BiocManager package which is required to load the rhdf5 package but there are no functions for mplus listed in that second link. The answer must be in the mplus.R source code but I can't find it anywhere. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source code right after sending off that question. I won't delete it incase someone might find this useful.

The mplus.R code required to view plots can be find in the first link posted in the question. It's under the section titled "The File mplus.R" but it must be copied and pasted into your r console or script and ran.